# How to delete millions of relationships off a single node with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a large graph in Neo4j and have an empty node that is connected via 11 million relationships in graph that I need to remove. I know that if I just delete the node I will leave behind all the hanging relationships but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to remove them. I have tried the following CYPHER commands but they hang and fail to complete:

```
MATCH (n:Label {uid: ''}) DETACH DELETE n;
```

and

```
MATCH (n:Label {uid: ''})-[r]-() DELETE r;
```

I'm working under the assumption that there are not enough resources to load the 11 million relationship subgraph in memory in order to detach and delete the node. Is there any way to loop over the relationships in order to lower the required system resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the relationships in batches and then delete the node

```
MATCH (n:Label {uid: ''})-[r]-() 
WITH r
LIMIT 1000
DELETE r;
```

If you run that successively you will delete the relationships in small batches. Play with the limit amount to see what your running system will tolerate resource wise.

Comment: Perfect, thank you; I was trying something similar but didn't have the "WITH r" part and it was falling over.

Comment: Perfect, it seemed to handle 1 million without a problem so I just wrote a little bit of python to repeat the call 12 times using the bolt driver. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use [`apoc.periodic.commit`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) function from the apoc library:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit(
  'MATCH (n:Label {uid: {uid}})-[r]->() 
   WITH r LIMIT {limit}
   DELETE r 
   RETURN COUNT(r)', {
     limit: 1000,
     uid: ...
})
```

2) You can delete the node, and then create it again with [`apoc.create.node`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) function:

```
MATCH (n:Label {uid: 2})
WITH n, {labels: labels(n), properties: properties(n)} AS data
DETACH DELETE n
WITH data
CALL apoc.create.node(data.labels, data.properties) yield node AS newNode
RETURN newNode
```

Comment: I didn't have APOC installed on the server but I'll ask the dev ops to add it. I can see how 1) might work but won't 2) have the same problem I'm currently experiencing in that the system cannot detach and delete so many relationships in one go based upon the system resources I have available?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Neo4j 4.0 or above, then this is the best way:

```
MATCH (n:Label {uid: ''})-[r]-() 
CALL { 
  WITH r 
  DELETE r 
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 1000 ROWS;
```